# How to use variable from mySQL DB in Doctrine?

Tags: php, sql, symfony, doctrine

I have problem with doctrine. My task is to set new Product with Category from other table. Category name is unique. Category and Product tables are in onetomany relation. When I make :

```
        $brand = new Category();
        $brand->setBrand('Beers');

        $beer = new Product();
        $beer->setModel('Bavaria');
        $beer->setBrand($brand);
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $em->persist($brand);
        $em->persist($beer);
        $em->flush();
```

It's all fine. But when I make this query with other model name (p.ex. Heineken) I have duplicated brand name. I want to have 1 brand name like wine, vodka, beers. I don't want to create each time brand name if it exists when I make query.
Thanks for answers.

Comment: try to test if the brand Existe if yes use it if not create it

Comment: I though that there is some method for that in Doctrine not if if.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to let the user choose amongst Categories you could use a form with an EntityType.

If you want to let the user type a name and create the category if it doesn't exist you could do it like this :

```
$newBrand = 'userInput';
$em       = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$category = $em->getRepository('YouBundle:YouEntity')->findOneBy(array('brand' => $newBrand));
if ($category == null) {
    $category = new Category();
    $category->setBrand($newBrand);
    $em->persist($category);
} 
$beer = new Product();
$beer->setModel('Bavaria');
$beer->setBrand($category); // If you need to use $category in you view don't forget $category->addProduct($beer);
$em->persist($beer);
$em->flush();
```

PS : mySQL has a create or update directive but I wouldn't advise it here since you will need to match all fields.

Comment: Dont forget the Doctrine mapping.